# отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "size", соответствующие списку аргументов

Tags: c++

Хочу узнать размер массива стрингов без конкретного количиства слов
Сами слова имеют тип string

````
txt = new string[]{ "The", "more", "we", "know", "the", "world",",", "the", "more", "we", "don't", "know", "it","."};

void LetterCount() {
        cout << "Enter symbol ('e' != 'E'): ";
        cin >> sym;
        for (int i = 0; i < size(txt); i++)
        {
            cout << txt[i] << " "; 
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size(txt); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size(txt[i]); j++)
            {
                if (txt[i][j] == sym) {                   
                    if (count == 0) {
                        count++;
                        cout << j + 1 << endl;
                    }
                    cout << txt[i];
                    if (txt[i] == txt[i]) {
                        break;
                    }   
                }
            }
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    ```
    но выдаёт ошибку сказанную в заголовке вопроса.
````

Comment: а что такое txt? массив? vector? string? что то пользовательское?

Comment: согласен, не дал конкретики, это string, и есть проблема в том что нельзя использовать vector и stl библиотеки.

txt = new string[]{ "The", "more", "we", "know", "the", "world",",",
"the", "more", "we", "don't", "know", "it","."};

вот так он выглядит

Comment: Так, как вы описали — `string*txt` — `size()` не работает для указателей. По указателю невозможно определить, на какое количество элементов он указывает. Воспользуйтесь, например, вектором.

Comment: @Harry и что вы посоветуете сделать? При разыменовании выводит лишь 3 элемента из массива вместо всех

Comment: для строк - .length(), для динамических массивов - размер нужно отдельно хранить. И если что - string -  это тоже часть stl. Так что я бы использовал stl и пинал того, кто задал такое задание

Comment: @KoVadim у меня такие же вопросы к тому кто создал задания, ну радует хотя бы что string можно использовать

Comment: напишите решение с вектором, отладьте его. А потом уже попробуйте переделать на динамический массив (если так сильно нужно автору), хотя  я бы на коленке сделал свой микровектор и использовал бы его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так, но это если статический массив.
Если динамически вводить - то нужно держать счетчик.
Вместо вложенного цикла можно использовать поиск символа в строке `strchr()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const char* txt[]{ "The", "more", "we", "know", "the", "world",",", "the", "more", "we", "don't", "know", "it","."};

void LetterCount() 
{
    cout << "Enter symbol ('e' != 'E'): ";
    char sym;
    cin >> sym;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(txt)/sizeof(char*); i++)
        cout << txt[i] << " "; 
    cout << endl;
    
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(txt)/sizeof(char*); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(txt[i]); j++)
            if (txt[i][j] == sym) 
            {                   
                count++;
                cout << j + 1 << " " << txt[i] << " ";
                break;
            }
    cout <<  "\nNumber of words with the symbol '" << sym << "' is " << count << "\n";
}
 
int main() 
{
  LetterCount();
}
```

Comment: Добавьте - "и не передавать `txt` в качестве аргумента функции", а то это будет следующим вопросом :)

Answer (score 0):

Вычисление размера выделенной памяти для массивов в стандарте не присутствует. В Си обычно используют ключевые элементы конца массива. В вашем случае попробуйте поставить ключевое слово, и по нему определите само количество элементов.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
using std::string;
string * const txt = new string[]{ "The", "more", "we", "know",
  "the", "world",",", "the", "more", "we", "don't", "know",
  "it",".","THE_END"};
int main(){
  string * j = txt ;
  while  ( * j not_eq "THE_END" )
    ++ j ;
  std :: cout << "количество слов = " << j - txt << std :: endl ;
}
```

количество слов = 14

Comment: очень плохой код. очень. Я даже не знаю, есть ли в стандарте гарантия, что строковая константа будет гарантированно иметь тот же адрес. Ну и форматированние ...

Comment: @KoVadim А при чем тут строковые константы?...

Comment: я о выражении `* j not_eq "THE_END"`

Comment: @KoVadim Так это же сравнение строки (`string * j`), а не указателей...

Comment: ах точно, почему я решил что там указатели... но все равно, ужасненько.